Can Microsoft Edge send browsing history to Microsoft for targeted advertising?
In Google Chrome, if you synchronize your browsing history between multiple devices, then Google can use your browsing history for advertising purposes.  Unless you disable this in your Google Account (see below).
Question: If you synchronize your browsing history between devices using Microsoft Edge, does it also analyse your browsing history e.g. for advertising?


Yes, it can.
Unlike Google Account, there is no opt-out for this in Microsoft Account.
There is a separate setting which allows you to send browsing history for advertising etc, even if you do not sync your history between multiple devices.

How do I turn on personalized web experiences or browsing history sync
in Microsoft Edge? To share your browsing history for a personalized
web experience, do the following:

In Microsoft Edge, select Settings and more  > Settings  > Privacy, search, and services .

Under Personalize your web experience, turn on Improve your web experience by allowing Microsoft to use your browsing history from
this account for personalizing advertising, search, news and other
Microsoft services.


To sync your browsing history across devices:

In Microsoft Edge, select Settings and more  > Settings  > Profiles  > Sync .

Turn on the History setting.



See support.microsoft.com: Browsing history on the privacy dashboard.

Note that telemetry is embedded into Edge. For Enterprise users, some can be turned off, e.g., https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-enterprise-privacy-settings . Use a tool such as Glasswire to see how much is sent to MS and its affiliates. If privacy is important, consider other browsers.
